# pseudo-random URL generation

Tags: php, javascript, python, url, random

I'm writing python code to parse data from http://www.istockphoto.com/ and it seems like the URL that is generated from a search seems to be pseudo-random; For example if you do a 'photos' search for 'meow' you get the URL: http://www.istockphoto.com/search/text/meow/filetype/photos/source/basic#e2430b3

I've looked at the source code carefully, but since I don't know much about PHP/javascript (I assume that's how the URL is being generated), I can't figure out exactly which lines of code are generating this URL.  Could someone please point me in the right direction and show me which lines of code are responsible for the URL?

Comment: It's probably just an internal identifier that's kept around for some time to refer to that search. Doesn't have to be pseudo-random and could well be sequential, too.

Comment: The portion after `#` is probably for AJAX pagination. It changes every time you click on a page number.

Comment: from what i can tell, the part after the # is the same identifier for each particular search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a (pseudo-)random url, as the first part is clearly unique for your search: `http://www.istockphoto.com/search/text/meow/filetype/photos/source/basic`

The last part, `#e2430b3` is just an anchor to somewhere on the page, or used by some scripts.
It is not used by the query, as you can type the url without this part and it works the same.

This part perhaps can be used by the server as a cache identifier, to speed up repetitive requests.

Comment: i did see that i didn't need the last part after the # to get to the results; however, if i want to get to other pages of the results, then i do need this part.  that's ultimately what i'm after, being able to access all the URLs of all the search results, no matter how many there are.  for this, i suspect i do need the part after the #.  any thoughts?

Comment: In fact this website uses a lot of javascript to display the good page, and totally doesn't work without it! It will be hard to do what you want, and even if you can do it, a minor change on the website will break your program. Try to see if the website have some kind of API to access photos, it will be the easier way.